# Convert a tiff into a buffered image (Java)

Tags: java, file, bufferedimage, tiff, javax.imageio

I need to convert a tiff file into a BufferedImage. I wrote the following code:

```
String filepath = "C:\\tiffFolder\\";
String filename = "myTiffImage.tif";
File myFile = new File (filepath + filename); 
BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(myFile);
```

I know for sure myFile is correctly instantiated: the problem is that after the fourth line of code img is still null.

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks so much!

**Edit**

Solved, I used the following code:

```
FileSeekableStream stream = new FileSeekableStream(filepath + filename);
TIFFDecodeParam decodeParam = new TIFFDecodeParam();
decodeParam.setDecodePaletteAsShorts(true);
ParameterBlock params = new ParameterBlock();
params.add(stream);
RenderedOp image1 = JAI.create("tiff", params);
BufferedImage img = image1.getAsBufferedImage();
```

Comment: What does myFile.canRead() return? [between line 3 and 4]

Comment: @Burkhard, it returns true

Comment: @DanieleMilani Check what does the following line print out : `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(ImageIO.getReaderFileSuffixes()));` On my machine it is `[bmp, jpg, jpeg, wbmp, png, gif]`. No `tif`.

Comment: Try use another image (jpg), I'm not sure if ImageBuffer support tif format.

Comment: @johnchen902 it prints [bmp, jpg, wbmp, jpeg, png, gif]... i think that this is the problem! Is it possible to add tif and tiff to the ImageIo supported suffixes?

Comment: @Sk1X1 I need to convert tif into BufferReader: is it possible?

Comment: @DanieleMilani: yes, but not with ImageIO. Take a look at JAI (details in my answer).

Comment: @DanieleMilani Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/q/9111177/2040040

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are trying to read a file format that is not supported by ImageIO.

As johnchen902 pointed out, the `ImageIO.getReaderFileSuffixes()` returns a list of suffixes that are supported. tiff is not in that list. That's why you cannot read it that way. Some external libaries might help you.
For instance: The Java Advanced Imaging API supports TIFF. Details [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/jai-142803.html).

Comment: Link fixed. Sorry for that.